# Flask doesn't see my css file

Tags: css, flask

In order to start learning Flask i created project called first_flask_exp which has a structure like that:

```
first_flask_exp
--first_flask_exp.py
--templates
----entry.html
--static
----images
------checkered.png
----css
------entry-style.css
```

first_flask_exp.py contains the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, get_flashed_messages, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>/')

def show_entry():
    return render_template('entry.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The only template entry.html contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Entry point</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/entry-style.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

</head>
<body>
    ENTER
</body>
</html>
```

And my entry-style.css is:

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

The problem is that my template's body is rendered red only when i put css file into static folder(not in any subfolder) and edit link to it like that:

{{ url_for('static', filename='entry-style.css') }}

Please help me to store resources like good practices advise =)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also should've added that Chrome's firebug shows error GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/css/entry-style.css 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: The code you've provided seems to be working just fine for me. The body's background is red and the directory structure works.

Comment: Hmm.. I've just recreated css folder directly from PyCharm and now it works! Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Sounds like it's a good idea to delete the question - it won't be useful to future visitors.